# Can not run unit test: No constructor 'Future.value' declared in class 'Future'

Tags: dart

I have a new dart project but I fail to add unit tests.

But I am new to DART so perhaps I am punished as all rookies should ... or should they!?

**Error when running unit tests**

```
Error: Exception: No constructor 'Future.value' declared in class 'Future'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Future.value'
Receiver: Type: class 'Future'
Arguments: []
Stack Trace: #0      _defer (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/main/webapp/dart/chessmodel/test/packages/unittest/unittest.dart:671:20)
#1      _ensureInitialized (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/main/webapp/dart/chessmodel/test/packages/unittest/unittest.dart:830:11)
#2      ensureInitialized (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/main/webapp/dart/chessmodel/test/packages/unittest/unittest.dart:809:21)
#3      group (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/main/webapp/dart/chessmodel/test/packages/unittest/unittest.dart:585:20)
#4      main (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/main/webapp/dart/chessmodel/test/test_runner.dart:9:8)
FAIL
```

**pub info**

```
€ pub --version
Pub 0.4.7+1.r21548
€ pub cache list
{"packages":
    {"browser":{"version":"0.4.7+1","location":"/Users/gunnar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.4.7+1"},
     "meta":{"version":"0.4.7+1","location":"/Users/gunnar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-0.4.7+1"},
     "stagexl":{"version":"0.7.4","location":"/Users/gunnar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stagexl-0.7.4"},
     "unittest":{"version":"0.4.7+1","location":"/Users/gunnar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/unittest-0.4.7+1"}}}
```

**Eclipse plugin**

```
Dart Editor for Eclipse 0.4.7.r21548    com.google.dart.eclipse.feature.feature.group   dartlang.org
```

**test_runner.dart**

```
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_enhanced_config.dart';

import 'ChessColor_test.dart' as color_test;

void main() {
  useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration();

  group('Enum tests', color_test.main);
}
```

**ChessColor_test.dart**

```
library color_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {
  test('isWhite', () =>
    expect(true, WHITE.isWhite())
  );
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your editor plugin is up-to-date but that your SDK itself is not. If you run dart --version from the CLI what is the result?

Comment: € dart --version
Dart VM version: 0.4.7.1_r21537 (Tue Apr 16 01:34:53 2013)

Comment: Actually, could you try running pub install again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

- Take a look at dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart. Do you see a Future.value factory constructor? If not, then your SDK is not the right version. I would check this both from the command line and from within the editor.
- If you do see it in the SDK, try exiting and restarting the editor. I'm speculating here, but when we saw this once in house, it behaved as though there was a cached copy of the async library that was out of date, and restarting made the issue go way.